# Crash (SIGILL) loading native lib on Android: how to get ARM instruction?

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, v8

I compiled v8 for ARM and it loads fine on the majority of arm6/7 phones. Some specific devices like the HTC Wildfire S crash when loading the native library.

This is the `SIGILL` (invalid instruction) I get:

```
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 312, tid: 312  >>> org.myapp <<<
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 4 (SIGILL), fault addr 81494f98
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000001  r1 00000003  r2 81494f8e  r3 81494f8c
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 8198a26c  r5 00000003  r6 00000004  r7 00000000
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 42189eac  r9 00000374  10 0000ce04  fp bef6765c
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 8124695c  sp bef67658  lr b0001169  pc 81494f98  cpsr 80000010
31-31/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00494f98  /data/data/org.myapp/lib/libjv8.so
```

I could use `ndk-stack` to get the specific line in v8 that's crashing, but it actually refers to a macro so I don't know which specific instruction is being executed.

I tried to connect to the device with `gdb-server`, but it doesn't give me more details about the instruction:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x81494f98 in ?? ()
```

So I'm a bit lost. Is there a way to translate `0x81494f98` to a specific ARM instruction?

Comment: How about using the ndk objdump on the .so file?  `arm-whatever-objdump -d libjv8.so` will produce a dissasembly which you can grep for the appropriate address by figuring out or guessing the map offset, or for that specific instruction.  Of course you could also manually decode it using the ARM reference manuals.  Given the context, it's probably trying to use a hardware extension which doesn't exist.

Comment: That's the address. Use addr2line with that (actually value on last line, after pc - you can notice they are similar) on so file to see the instruction.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I could find any `81494f98` in objdump's output. How can I figure out the correct address to grep?

Comment: @auselen `ndk-stack` already gave me which line of code this address refers to (which is a macro inside v8's `isolate.cc`). `addr2line` gives me nothing though: `?? ??:0`

Comment: You probably want 0x494f98 the rest is likely load offset.  And it is an address, not an opcode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're the man! So it refers to `494f98: e30f1fff  movw r1, #65535 ; 0xffff`, which apparently is a armv7 only instruction. Looks like I have a compilation issue :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ChrisStratton, this is how I was able to find the specific ARM instructions that causes a SIGILL:

```
$ arm-whatever-objdump -d <lib_path> | grep <pc_address>
```

or in my case:

```
$ arm-whatever-objdump -d libjv8.so | grep 494f98
```

It produced the following line:

```
494f98: e30f1fff movw   r1, #65535  ; 0xffff
```